# Duplicate app icons in Ubuntu Software - install and remove

Tags: gnome, software-installation, software-center, libreoffice

After uninstalling some apps (e.g. a LibreOffice package) and installing them again after some time there are two app bars in Ubuntu Software menu - one with "remove" and one with "install" button for every app previously uninstalled.

And none of those buttons work - the bar starts loading, but doesn't finish installing/removing an app (in every case it's pretty the same).

What's wrong? Do I have to do some special disc cleaning after that issue?
Or will just `sudo apt-get autoremove` be enough?

I use Ubuntu 16.04 with GNOME instead of preinstalled Unity.

Comment: There are a large number of libre-office packages. can you provide further detail? run `dpkg-query -l libreoffice*` to understand the confusion. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: dpkg-query -l libreoffice*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  libreoffice    1:5.4.4~rc2- amd64        office productivity suite (metapa
un  libreoffice-av <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  libreoffice-av 1:5.4.4~rc2

Answer (score 1):

*Ubuntu Software* shows applications which are available both as debs and snaps, in which case you may see the same application twice. LibreOffice is one such application.